# in-place-edit in Django/Python not working

Tags: django

i am looking to use inplaceedit in my django app. I did the installation and it went well :

```
pip install django-inplaceedit==0.77
```

On top of the base.html i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Static assets - Used to load the Favicon -->
{% load static %}
{% load inplace_edit %}
{% inplace_toolbar %}
....
```

I get the following error :

```
Exception Value:    
Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'inplaceeditform.templatetags.inplace_edit': No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
```

if I keep following the turtorial and add the following to the `urls.py`, I get :

```
...  File "C:\Users\franky.doul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pyth
-packages\inplaceeditform\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.conf.urls.defaults'
```

Anything that I am missing or doing wrong please?

Comment: You have installed `django-inplaceedit` [0.77](https://pypi.org/project/django-inplaceedit/0.77/) which was released in 2012. Even the latest version [1.4.1](https://pypi.org/project/django-inplaceedit/1.4.1/) was released in 2015. It's not going to work with recent versions of Django, unless you fork the project and update it.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i will take it out.

Comment: is there an alternative which works with the recent versions of Django please ?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of, and I'm afraid library recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow.